# Can't see how to re-arrange this formula

Tags: calculus, limits

On a recent calc 1 exam for the chapter on limits, my professor had this formula with the instruction to rewrite so it was continuous as $x=5$.  I was unable to complete it, and even when I looked at it later I couldn't figure it out.  The function approaches $.25$ as $x$ gets closer to $5$, but the numerator equals $0$ when $x=5$.

Is there something really simple that I'm just missing?

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 7x + 16}- \sqrt6}{(x-5)\sqrt{x+1}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\sqrt(x^2 - 7x + 16) - \sqrt6}{(x-5)\sqrt(x+1)} \frac{\sqrt(x^2 - 7x + 16) + \sqrt6}{\sqrt(x^2 - 7x + 16) + \sqrt6}=
$$
$$
= \frac{x^2 - 7x +10}{(x-5)\sqrt(x+1)(\sqrt(x^2 - 7x + 16) + \sqrt6})=  \frac{(x-2)(x-5)}{(x-5)\sqrt(x+1)(\sqrt(x^2 - 7x + 16) + \sqrt6)}
$$
$$
=  \frac{(x-2)}{\sqrt(x+1)(\sqrt(x^2 - 7x + 16) + \sqrt6)}
$$

Comment: +1 for the answer. I think it's an awful question for a calculus exam.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Multiply numerator and denominator with $\sqrt{x^2-7x+16}+\sqrt 6$. You should obtain $$\frac{x^2-7x+10}{(x-5)\bigl(\sqrt{x^2-7x+16}+\sqrt 6\bigr)\sqrt{x+1}},$$
which can be simplified.